# How to mount HDD containing data to a new system build

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, fstab

**Scenario:**
Installed Ubuntu Server (ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64) onto new server. I want to install **2** additional HDDs containing existing data and mount them on the new server.

**Questions:**
After physically installing the drives in the new server chasis...
  1. Are the below steps correct?
  2. Is *nofail* advised in */etc/fstab*?
  3. Is the number *2* advised (sys check) in */etc/fstab*?

**UPDATED below to reflect comments**

Note the UUID after running blkid:
`/dev/sda2: LABEL="birdy1" UUID="111tru-c900-5100" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="birdy2" UUID="uhsdb1-xxxx-6463" TYPE="ext4"`

Create mount points:
`:~$ sudo mkdir -p /media/{birdy2,birdy3}`

Duplicate fstab to maintain default config for backup or revert purposes:
`:~$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.20171023.bak`

Edit fstab to automount drive:
`:~$ sudo vi /etc/fstab`

Add these lines to the end of the file (for ext4 file system) and save:
`UUID=111tru-c900-5100    /media/birdy2   ext4    defaults,nofail     0        2
UUID=uhsdb1-xxxx-6463    /media/birdy3   ext4    defaults,nofail     0        2`

Mount drive after fstab modifications, check for errors and make corrections to prevent any system failure do to misspellings or incorrect entries:
`:~$ sudo mount -a`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your process, I didn't see any issue and seems the right process to mount the two news disks. After editing the `/etc/fstab` file, do a `mount -a` to ensure to take care the fstab modifications. This will also ensure that your server will properly restart as any bad line may prevent your server from starting properly. If you are unsure, just do a copy of the fstab file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks you. I have edited my instructions to reflect your suggestions.